# How to restart windows service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, windows-services

I got a snippet from http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/ to restart windows service, but i am not sure as to where to place the code?

I need to restart windows service after my it is installed in my application.

Thanks!

**EDITED**

```
private void ProjectInstaller_OnAfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnAfterInstall(e);
        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MyServiceName", Environment.MachineName);
        sc.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        sc.Stop();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        sc.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
```

Comment: Moderator: I have got the solution. I appreciate the comments entered but none of them have helped me hence i wish to delete the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should put in the after install. The installer will probably start the service anyway after installation, and this seems like a messy way to do it. You can create a small app or .dll that can do this if you really need it and can be called from the installer itself when everything is finished. However I would investigate **why** you need to restart the service after installation, as that mostly points to a bug in your program. Should be easier to resolve that.

This snipped should do the trick of restarting. Do not use sleep as service might take more than that time to start/stop and you will get an exception.

```
var sc = new ServiceController("MyService");
sc.Stop();
sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
sc.Start();
sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some application that installs the service, the code to restart (or otherwise control the service) should run in your application