# Restart Windows 8.1 local Service from a C++ app?

Tags: c++, winapi, device-driver

I have a C++ desktop app that talks to a foreign (not written by me) Windows 8.1 Local Service.  The service talks to a USB device.  Unfortunately, the service has a bug that causes it to become unresponsive if the USB device is detached, even if detached properly using the USB device manager utility.  Currently I have to go into the Windows 8.1 Local Services control panel and restart the service manually.

I can detect if the service is unresponsive from my app.  So what I want to do is if upon startup I detect that condition, I restart the service from my app.  Is there a WinApi or other call or technique available that will help me do that?  I've found some C# examples like this one:

[How to restart windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752576/how-to-restart-windows-service)

But nothing for C++.  I am using Visual Studio 2013 for development.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774179/windows-service-starting-stopping-another-service

Comment: Does your desktop app run elevated? If not then you are probably out of luck. You'd likely need to create a separate process, best as a guardian service, to keep this other service alive.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks.  What I could do is launch another app that would prompt the user for elevated permissions and do the restart.  A bit convoluted, but less of a hassle than instructing a novice user on using the Local Services control panel to restart the service.

Comment: Install a dedicated guardian service to do the restarting and then the user can be shielded completely

Answer (score 0):

Just call [`ControlService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682108(v=vs.85).aspx). [Filler]

Comment: I think you should add a brief description of the function and so make padding useless.